# To show Tooltip on focus of a textbox until user puts data into textbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, tooltip

I have a complex WPF application based on MVVM. I want to create an assistance mode for my application.So for example I am thinking that a customized tootip will open (on a textbox) when user opens the screen and remain opened until user puts some data into it. As user puts data,the focus will automatically shift to the next control and another tooltip for that control will open and this way the flow will go on.One thing, I want to code in XAML only..Any suggestion friends ???

Comment: You could predefine your tooltips and bind them appropriately, then use a trigger to force focus from one control to another once data is entered into the proper textblock. Have you tried anything like that?

Comment: yes tooltips are predefined and bound appropriately.I am finding for a generic style for tooltip.then i will apply that style to all the textblocks.I have already used a trigger to bind a bool property(shown below).<Style.Triggers> <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAssistanceModeActive}" Value="True"> <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True"/> </DataTrigger> </Style.Triggers>
@aqua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be easier to modify the template of text box with some help from attached properties.

Make a class to hold helper attached properties. Let's call it `Assistance` and it will have two attached properties:

1. AssistanceTipContent of type `object`.
2. IsAssistanceActive of type `bool`.

Then the custom Style/Template for Text Box (based on default Aero theme):

```
<!--Add this xmlns definition to the root of the file-->
xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
....
<!--Then in resources-->
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TextBoxBorder" EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#ABADB3" Offset="0.05"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#E2E3EA" Offset="0.07"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#E3E9EF" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome>
                    <Popup x:Name="AssistanceTip"
                           IsOpen="False"
                           AllowsTransparancy="True">
                        <!--TODO: Add Background/BorderBrush/BorderThicknes to this Border so it matches ToolTip style-->
                        <Border>
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=(Assistance.AssistanceTipContent), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Text}" Value=""/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(Assistance.IsAssistanceActive), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="AssistanceTip" Property="IsOpen" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now your use will be something like:

```
<TextBox local:Assistance.AssistanceTipContent="Some text to help the user"
         local:Assistance.IsAssistanceActive="{Binding IsAssistanceModeActive}"
         ..../>
```

This removes data triggers (to view model data) from styles and makes it quite generic approach.

[The change of focus is not handled here, I understand that you've accomplished that already.]